# compile from .py to .pyc then use Cython to compile to .c file

Tags: python, cython

I'm compile Python file .py to .pyc file
In test.py file there is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print "Hello, World!"
```

Then compile to .pyc with :

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile("test.py")
```

Then I'm trying to compile it to .c file with Cython but tell me this error

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
[unprintable code]
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyc:1:1: Decoding error, missing or incorrect coding=<encoding-name> at top of source (cannot decode with encoding 'utf8': invalid continuation byte)
```

With .py file Cython work greats but with .pyc don't

What should I do ?

thanks.

Comment: try replacing `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` with `#coding=utf-8`

Comment: Because you have a misconception here: Cython *never* works on pyc-files. That wouldn't e.g. work for those cases where you embed C/C++ into the file (pyx). So - just don't do it, and use your working approach with .py.

Comment: Rename your source code to `abc.pyx`. And try to `cython abc.pyx`

Comment: The OP had a misconcept about how Cython works, and after clarification this question becomes unnecessary.